# Sending files from php to another api wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to send files from Wordpress to external API, here is example of my function for sending simple json

```
 $customer_ids = array('CustomerIds' => [$user_email]);
 $recomended_url = 'https://example.com';
 $recomended_response = wp_remote_post($recomended_url, array(
        'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
        'body' => json_encode(customer_ids),
        'method' => 'POST',
        'data_format' => 'body',
  ));
```

But in body i need to send file, i know path of my file

```
$path = wp_upload_dir();
$file = $path['path']."/CUSTOMERS.csv";
```

Is it simple that i need just to do **'body' => json_encode($file)** or i need to get file content,and say it is a file??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use that :

```
<?php

$local_file = 'file_path'; //path to a local file on your server
$post_fields = array(
    'name' => 'value',
);
$boundary = wp_generate_password( 24 );
$headers  = array(
    'content-type' => 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $boundary,
);
$payload = '';
// First, add the standard POST fields:
foreach ( $post_fields as $name => $value ) {
    $payload .= '--' . $boundary;
    $payload .= "\r\n";
    $payload .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' . $name .
        '"' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $payload .= $value;
    $payload .= "\r\n";
}
// Upload the file
if ( $local_file ) {
    $payload .= '--' . $boundary;
    $payload .= "\r\n";
    $payload .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' . 'upload' .
        '"; filename="' . basename( $local_file ) . '"' . "\r\n";
    //        $payload .= 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' . "\r\n";
    $payload .= "\r\n";
    $payload .= file_get_contents( $local_file );
    $payload .= "\r\n";
}
$payload .= '--' . $boundary . '--';
$response = wp_remote_post( $req,
    array(
        'headers'    => $headers,
        'body'       => $payload,
    )
);
?>
```

Comment: I dont thisnk this is proper answer :(

Comment: it's not what you search ? what do you want so ?